# @casl/vue: What should by ability.js file look like?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, casl

I'm trying to integrate [@casl/vue](https://github.com/stalniy/casl/tree/master/packages/casl-vue) with Vue 3, and I'm afraid I'm having problems.

Per the instructions, I've added the following to my /main.js:

```
import { abilitiesPlugin } from '@casl/vue';
import ability from './services/ability';

app.use(abilitiesPlugin, ability, {
  useGlobalProperties: true
})
```

So far, so good. However, it's unclear what I should put in /services/ability.js.

I tried the following (based on [this](https://casl.js.org/v5/en/guide/intro#basics)), and it works:

```
import { defineAbility } from '@casl/ability';

export default defineAbility((can, cannot) => {
  can('manage', 'all');
  cannot('delete', 'User');
});
```

But, of course, this doesn't allow me to use different permissions for different users.

So I tried the following instead (based on [this](https://casl.js.org/v5/en/guide/intro#conditions)):

```
import { defineAbility } from '@casl/ability';

export default (user) => defineAbility((can) => {
  can('read', 'Article');

  if (user.isLoggedIn) {
    can('update', 'Article', { authorId: user.id });
    can('create', 'Comment');
    can('update', 'Comment', { authorId: user.id });
  }
});
```

...and that doesn't work. In the console, I see:

```
plugin.ts:12 Uncaught Error: Please provide an Ability instance to abilitiesPlugin plugin
    at l (plugin.ts:12:11)
    at Object.use (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3812:21)
    at main.js?t=1651580949947:29:5
```

Got any hints? I'm finding the documentation to be pretty unclear. A practical example would really help me!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It means you must pass plugins as an instance of Ability

const ability = new Ability()

```
.use(abilitiesPlugin, ability, {
  ....
  })
```